# jquery Item filtering width multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, filtering

Could you please help me? I started a filter width multiple values to sorting items. I had already made the selection of the filter items and pass their values to the container as class names. But how can I view properly just those item where the container classes and the item classes matching?

Here's my code to see it clearly:

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if ($('.filter').length > 0) {
console.log('van');
  //This makes data-filter to class
  $('.active').each(function() {
    var featureClassName = $(this).attr('data-filter');

    $('#container').addClass(featureClassName);
  });

  //On click remove classes and collect classes from active filters
  $('.type > .filter').on('click', function() {
console.log('click');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    $('#container').removeClass();

    if ($('.type > .filter').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.active').each(function() {
        var filterClasses = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        $('#container').addClass(filterClasses);
      });
    }
    // Hide item if not match, visible if match

  });
}
</script>
<style>
.active {color:red;}

</style>

<div id="filters">
  <ul class="type">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value1" class="active">value1</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value2">value2</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="type">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value3 active">value3</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value4">value4</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="type">
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value5">value5</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value6 active">value6</li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter="value7">value7</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="container" class="value1 value3 value6">
  <div class="item otherclassname value3 value6">item1</div>
  <div class="item value4 value7 otherclassname">item2</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value4 value7">item3</div>
  <div class="item value3 value5 otherclassname">item3.1</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value4 value5">item4</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value4 value6">item5</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value3 value5">item6</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value3 value6">item7</div>
  <div class="item value4 otherclassname value6">item8</div>
  <div class="item otherclassname value3 value7">item9</div>
  <div class="item value3 value6 otherclassname">item10</div>
  <div class="item value4 otherclassname value7">item11</div>
</div>
```

At this point I have active filters and their data goes to classes. Now I don't know how to make visible if matching classes to apear and hide items that doesn't have matching classes to the container classes.

Could you please give me some help what to use for matching?

Comment: why not use a [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) if you are filtering - eg `$('#container').filter(function() { return $(this).hasClass(filterDataAttribute); })`

Comment: Your snippet is not working can you try edit and check?

Comment: @pete Thank you I had never use filter before but this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
function HideNoMatch() {
    var classes = $('#container')[0].className.split(' ');
    var childArr = $('#container').children();
    for (var item of childArr) {
        var flag = false;
        classes.map(function(e) {
            if (flag) {
                return false;
            }
            flag = item.className.indexOf(e) > -1 ? true : false;
        });
        flag ? null : $(item).hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: @VictorH Glad to hear it worked .This is the first time i posted an answer on Stackoverflow

Comment: @prince-prasad Thanks for improving the formatting .I will try to improve it next time onwards